# ImproperlyConfigured: There are duplicate field(s) in PackageAdmin.fieldsets

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a very simple model :

```
   class Package(models.Model):
    package_id = models.IntegerField()
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField('Subscription', blank=True, null=True)
```

here is the admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from auth.models import Subscription, Package

class PackageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('package_name', 'package_id')
    fieldsets = (
       (None, {
           'fields': ('package_name')
           }),
       ('Advanced options', {
           'fields': ('package_id')
           }),
    )

admin.site.register(Package, PackageAdmin)
```

This implementation give me the following error :

```
ImproperlyConfigured: There are duplicate field(s) in PackageAdmin.fieldsets
```

Any idea why ?

If I let the second 'fields' empty, I don't get the error.
But if I let the first 'fields' empty, I still have this error.

Comment: It's an odd error for it, but it just might be because your fields tuples aren't well formed. Try changing them to `('package_name',)` and `('package_id',)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Björn Kristinsson did solve my issue ([see in the comment of the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23648225/admin-fieldsets-give-me-duplicate-error/24994655#comment36319807_23648225))

> It's an odd error for it, but it just might be because your fields tuples aren't well formed. Try changing them to `('package_name',)` and `('package_id',)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from auth.models import Subscription, Package

class PackageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('package_name', 'package_id')
    fieldsets = (
       (None, {
           'fields': ('package_name',)
           }),
       ('Advanced options', {
           'fields': ('package_id',)
           }),
    )

admin.site.register(Package, PackageAdmin)
```

you must insert a comma at the end of each field

Answer (score 0):

A tuple with only one value needs **a comma ","** at the end of it.

So, you need to add **a comma ","** to the end of each tuple in your code as shown below:

```py
'fields': ('package_name',)
                         ↑ Here
```

```py
'fields': ('package_id',)
                       ↑ Here
```